# Grails Spring Security Plugin Trouble with User Rules

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've added the Grails Spring Security plugin to a scaffolded Grails 2.1.1 application.  I am setting up user rules so that only a ROLE_ADMIN user may edit, delete, update, or create. I've got this working except for delete. For some reason, my ROLE_USER users are still able to delete. Is there anything wrong with my rules below?

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
'/person/update/*':     ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/person/edit/*':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/person/delete':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/person/create':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],

'/county/update/*':     ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/county/delete':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/county/edit/*':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/county/create':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],

'/course/update/*':     ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/course/delete':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/course/edit/*':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/course/create':       ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],

'/':                    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],
'/**':                  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
```

]

Thanks!

Comment: When I hover over the Delete button, I notice the URL is /myapp/county/index, and not delete. When I tried to block /county/index for ROLE_USER, then the user is blocked out of everything...

Comment: Great answer from Burt, as usual. I just wanted to add that using IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED everywhere is probably not what you really want. You probably either want IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, or leave authentication off entirely, and just go with the role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I talk about this in the docs - see the warning about `actionSubmit` at http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html

As you're seeing the `actionSubmit` tag posts to the index action and Grails figures out which action to forward to based on a hidden input, but that's too late for Spring Security.

The fix is to use two forms and not use `actionSubmit`.

Comment: I'm sorry to have overlooked that, thank you very much for your help!